# Can I see google analytics data of site if I have only a track code?

Tags: google-analytics

I have track code (UA) of one site. 
Is there any way to see Google Analytics data of this site if I have only its track code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*No*, and with good reason.

The code is view-able in the page source.  If you don't have a Google account authorized with Google for the UA code, you can't see site stats.  If you could, think about the corporate abuse of looking at competitors data.